# How can I handle html files in Luminus which aren't in "resources"?

Tags: html, clojure, luminus, selmer

I have this:

```
(defn about-page []
    (layout/render "about.html" {:title "About"}))
```

But since I have moved the directory "templates" from "resources" to the root directory and on a server I might put it yet in another place, it doesn't work. I did it because I don't want the html templates to be embedded in the output jar.
So how can I make the code work, how can I get access to my html files in "templates" then?

And the same question for static images, css, js: I put them in the root directory for now, so they aren't in "resources". They're in "public" folder. However, when I refer to them as "public/css/css1.css", they aren't getting found, that is, the path localhost:3000/public/css/css1.css doesn't exist.

How can I tell Luminus where my statics are located now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Templates location

[Selmer's documentation describes how to change the location of the templates](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer#resource-path):

> By default the templates are located relative to the ClassLoader URL.
>   If you'd like to set a custom location for the templates, you can use
>   selmer.parser/set-resource-path! to do that:
>
> ```
> (selmer.parser/set-resource-path! "/var/html/templates/")
> ```
>
> It's also
>   possible to set the root template path in a location relative to the
>   resource path of the application:
>
> ```
> (set-resource-path! (clojure.java.io/resource "META-INF/foo/templates"))
> ```
>
> This allows the templates to be refrerenced
>   using include and extends tags without having to specify the full
>   path.
>
> To reset the resource path back to the default simply pass it a nil:
>
> ```
> (selmer.parser/set-resource-path! nil)
> ```
>
> The application will then look
>   for templates at this location. This can be useful if you're deploying
>   the application as a jar and would like to be able to modify the HTML
>   without having to redeploy it.

As you want your templates to be reload when you change them you should also remember that Selmer caches them:

> When rendering files Selmer will cache the compiled template. A
>   recompile will be triggered if the last modified timestamp of the file
>   changes. Note that changes in files referenced by the template will
>   not trigger a recompile. This means that if your template extends or
>   includes other templates you must touch the file that's being rendered
>   for changes to take effect.
>
> Alternatively you can turn caching on and off using
>   `(selmer.parser/cache-on!)` and `(selmer.parser/cache-off!)` respectively.

## Assets location

Handling of static resources is configured using [`site-defaults`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults#customizing) in your `<app>.middleware` namespace. You need to configure its' `:static` entry to use `:files` instead:

```
(-> site-defaults
  (assoc :static {:files "/var/www/html"}))
```

and you need to copy files from `resources/public` directory to that location.

Comment: do you know how can I get the root directory where my app is located? how can I refer to it from `:files`?

Comment: When you start your application the directory where you run the java process (e.g. by calling `lein`) will be set as your current working directory and all relative paths in your application will be resolved using that path. So you can just use for example `./../some-path`.

Comment: yes, for static that's working, but for `(selmer.parser/set-resource-path! "templates")` -- no. I've tried also `./templates`, although the absolute path is working.

Comment: Check if `<app>.layout` namespace doesn't interfere with your attempt to change the path. It calls `(parser/set-resource-path! (clojure.java.io/resource "templates"))` and might overriding your custom location.